# multiple image file paths in my include header.php file?

Tags: php, include, filepath

I made a header.php file and then i include it in my index.php. the problem is
i have my root folter which contains my index.php and submaps, these submaps contain my other page.php files. now when i include the header.php in main, the file paths are all okay, but let say if i want to go one or two directorys further, then the file/image paths ofcourse don't work anymore, how do i solve this? would i just need to make multiple header.php files(wouldn't really make sense) or can i work with some kind of if statement in the header.php? to see what file called it?

header.php

```
<header>

            <a href="#" title="praniels logo" class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.svg">
            </a>

        <nav class="floatfix nav">
            <div id="hamburgerknop"> 
                <a href="#" title="praniels logo" class="mobile-logo">
                    <img src="images/logo.svg">
                </a>
                <span id="hamburger">&#9776;</span>
            </div> 
                    <ul class="main-nav">
                        <li><a href="#" title="naar homepage">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="over-ons/over-ons.php" title="naar over ons">Over Ons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="producten/producten.php" title="naar producten">Producten</a></li>
                        <li><a href="workshops/workshops.php" title="naar workshops pagina">Workshops</a></li>
                        <li><a href="klanten/klanten.php" title="naar klantenpagina">Klanten</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact/contact.php" title="naar contactpagina">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="icon-nav">
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="icon icon-mono facebook" target=_"blank"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=nl" class="icon icon-mono twitter" target=_"blank"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com" class="icon icon-mono googleplus" target=_"blank"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-mono instagram"><span class="fa fa-instagram" target=_"blank"></span></a></li>

                    </ul>
        </nav>
</header>
```

then i include this file in my index.php

index.php

```
 <?php include('header.php') ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a prefix variable.

```
<?php $prefix = 'http(s)://path/to/root'; ?>
<img src="<?=$prefix?>/images/logo.svg">
```

Comment: superb, i figured it out this way :) tnx a lot